# how to manipulate strings in jQuery (especially, finding sub-string in a string)

Tags: jquery

let's say, for instance, I have this

```
<h2>I don't love Programming</h2>
```

I'd like to remove **'don't'** from the text inside the h2 tag.

So far, I've done this

```
var content = $(h2).text();
```

That's allow me to get the text **'I don't love Programming'**. But I need a way to locate **don't** and replace it by something else or simply remove it.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function:

```
var content = $(h2).text().replace("don't", "");
```

To come up with:

```
I love Programming
```

If you want to remove all instances of a string from given string, you can use regex with `/g` modifier:

```
var content = $(h2).text().replace(/don't/g, '');
```

Comment: @Caspar: jQuery is also javascript at its core. The `replace` function is what you need to use there :)

Comment: I agree completely with your answer, *replace* however is not a jQuery function. Just as a sidenote: the answer has just partially something to do with jQuery.